# Listbox scroll viewer - default scroll to bottom

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollviewer

I have a `ListBox` which has to be scrolled to bottom automatically. In my application, I have to detect if some items were already visibled to user and to do some business logic if so. I am using virtualization here which calls item (vm) properties only if it is visible.

For auto scroll, i am using `listbox.ScrollIntoView(listbox.SelectedItem);` which works perfect, the problem is that the `ScrollIntoView` will run only after the `ListBox` is already loaded and rendered which means that it first displays some items from its beginning and after that it will scroll to bottom... it is undesirable for me. I just want to scroll immediately to bottom (before the `ListBox` is rendered).

Here is my behavior for auto scroll to bottom:

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    base.OnAttached();
    this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged += AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
}

void AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is ListBox)
    {
        ListBox listbox = (sender as ListBox);
        if (listbox.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            listbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                listbox.UpdateLayout();
                if (listbox.SelectedItem != null)
                {
                    listbox.ScrollIntoView(listbox.SelectedItem);
                }
            }));
        }
    }
}

protected override void OnDetaching()
{
    base.OnDetaching();
    this.AssociatedObject.SelectionChanged -= AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged;
}
```

My `ListBox` is setted to `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` and its `ItemsSource` is binded to `ICollectionView` where i am using `MoveCurrentToLast`.

So the question is: is there any way how to scroll to bottom without rendering its top first?

Comment: AFAIK, scrolling is a process belonging to the VisualTree. If there is no Tree, there is no scrolling. Solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26274919/4558029)

Comment: Scrolling down is not a problem for me, works good... the problem is that it always shows some items from its beginning when initializing. I cant simply say: Hey, just scroll down to the bottom immediately without displaying the top! The problem for me is that I run some commands when the list reachs the top.

Comment: I've tried your code and cannot reproduce what you are describing. Can you provid some data (VM) to work with?

Comment: Can't you just `MoveCurrentToLast()` in your ViewModel c.tor and `ScrollIntoView` the last item at your ListBox Loaded event? Then... How can you perceive that "it first displays some items from its beginning"? That's invisible, if it even happens... What exactly is not working in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I've reproduced your attached command as a

```
public class MyBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
    {
```

to a XAML

```
    <ListBox SelectedItem="SelCust" Name="MyListBox" Loaded="MyListBox_Loaded" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}">
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <local:MyBehavior/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=LoadCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
```

where I've also added a binding for the Load event to the ViewModel

```
    public CustomerViewModel()
    {
        IList<Customer> customers = Customer.GetCustomers().ToList();
        _customerView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(customers);
        _customerView.MoveCurrentToLast();
        _customerView.CurrentChanged += CustomerSelectionChanged;

    }
    private void CustomerSelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // React to the changed selection
        Debug.WriteLine("Here");
        var sel = (sender as CollectionView).CurrentItem;
        if ( sel!= null)
        {
            //Do Something          
        }
    }
    private DelegateCommand loadCommand;
    public ICommand LoadCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (loadCommand == null)
            {
                loadCommand = new DelegateCommand(VMLoad);
            }
            return (ICommand)loadCommand;
        }
    }
    bool IsLoaded = false;
    private void VMLoad(object obj)
    {
        IsLoaded = true;
    }
```

and in the code-behind

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new CustomerViewModel();
    }

    private void MyListBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyListBox.ScrollIntoView(MyListBox.Items[MyListBox.Items.Count - 1]);
    }
```

When I debug it, I see that the this is the sequence of events fired:

1. `CurrentChanged` wiht the last item of the collection
2. `Loaded` handler **in the code-behind**
3. `LoadCommand` in the ViewModel and only **after** that
4. `ScrollIntoView` from the `AssociatedObject_SelectionChanged`

So basically I'm suggesting a couple of things:

- add (another) `ScrollIntoView` (for the last item of the collection) from the `Loaded` handler in the
  code-behind
- for whatever action you need to perform *when you have to detect if some items are already visible to user*, first check `IsLoaded` to exclude any transient effect

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply scroll to the last value in your collection after you set the DataContext or ItemSource? No data will render until you set your data context, and until you exit the constructor. To my understanding if you do the following to steps in sequence in the constructor, it should work as expected.

```cs
listBox.DataContext = _items;
listBox.ScrollIntoView(_items.Last());
```